# Cannot use public static bool in another script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, static, boolean

I have one script (called PauseMenu1) that only contains the following line:

```
public static bool IsOn = false;
```

I can access it in a second script (which handles raycasting) by typing

```
if (PauseMenu1.IsOn)
            return;
```

in the second script. This works fine to prevent raycasting when the pause menu is active.
Now here is my problem: If I paste the "if (PauseMenu1.IsOn) return;" line into a third script (FirstPersonController or MouseLook, which are standard asset scripts), it gives me an error that says:

> "Error CS0103  The name 'PauseMenu1' does not exist in the current context".

The second script (raycasting), in which the

```
if (PauseMenu1.IsOn)
            return;
```

line works, also includes the following lines:

```
[SerializeField] GameObject pauseMenu;

    public void Start()
    {
        PauseMenu1.IsOn = false;
    }
```

```
public void TogglePauseMenu()
    {
        pauseMenu.SetActive(!pauseMenu.activeSelf);
        PauseMenu1.IsOn = pauseMenu.activeSelf;
    }
```

pasting those into the other scripts gives me the same error:

> "Error CS0103 The name 'PauseMenu1' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: Are they both contained within the same namespace?

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by "they"?

Comment: The third script and PauseMenu1

Comment: I don"t think so, I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: You'll need to make the PauseMenu1 into a public and static class to access it this way.

Comment: @Confused Yes that too, thought I assumed his class was already static with the access '(PauseMenu1.IsOn)' in the second script

Comment: oh ok, how do i do that? Sorry i"m new.

Comment: Most classes are already public, so you just need to add `static` right after the word public, and before the name of the class  "PauseMenu1 ". This way you can directly access this class and its public and static members from anywhere in other code. This is frowned on in "real world programming", but in game programming it's super useful, and the only way to stay sane when using Unity.

Comment: @Confused Thats not true. Static variables can always be accessed even when the class is not static itself. OPs code works fine for me.

Comment: when i do that a get the folowing error

Comment: Static class 'PauseMenu1' cannot derive from type 'MonoBehaviour'. Static classes must derive from object.

Comment: Your PauseMenu1 doesn't need to be a MonoBehaviour (the word after the : after the class name). But if you're doing something Unity in the PauseMenu1, it might need to be. Then I think we're going to need someone like Armin or Daniel M to come up with better ways of fixing this, because I'd be making manager classes to do this kind of thing.

Comment: How do I make this work?

Comment: "(...)wich are standart asset scripts" On top of these scripts, is there something called `namespace`?

Comment: In the FirstPersonController script it says

Comment: namespace UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson

Comment: Remove that line and its brackets. Then it should work. [Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/namespace) are normal when it comes to typical software development with C#. In Unity they are rarely used and it seems like the standard asset scripts use them.

Comment: I did that and I still get the error: "Error CS0103 The name 'PauseMenu1' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: You removed `namespace UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson{ *Code of the class* } ` from the `FirstPersonController.cs`  and inside of **that** script you are still getting that error? Or do you still have the code snipped inside of `MouseLook.cs` and didn't remove the `namespace` from it?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. It was in the folder called standard assets, and therefor compiled before everything else.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptCompileOrderFolders.html